# Is Directory.EnumerateFiles locking the file it is trying to copy?

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I am trying to write a program to copy my SQL Database Backup files to a NAS. It was working before, but then I added in checking to see if the paths exist and now when it tries to copy the file it gets an exception saying "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2012.bak' because it is being used by another process."

I've checked process explorer and no other program is touching the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Code Below

```
namespace BackupCopy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set Source Path
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup";

            // Verify Source Path Exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }



            // Backup each file in Array
            foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath))
            {
                Backup(filename);
            }

        }

        public static void Backup(string filename)
        {
            // Pull filename from method input parameter
            string fileName = filename;

            // Set Paths
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup";
            string targetPath = @"\\prometheus\NAS\DB Backups\mercurys";

            // Verify Target Path Exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Target path does not exist.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths. 
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a file to another location and  
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There *is* another process with the given path open. For me, the Winternals [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has never failed to find open file handles given a file path - although it is possible the file is accessed via a (different path) mapping.

Comment: Read the question again, I am already using Process Explorer to check.

Comment: Read the comment again. I am saying "I doubt the correct usage of PE", nicely. In any case, collaborate the findings with `openfiles` (windows command) and `handle` (part of Winternals suite). Make the search as least restrictive as possible.

Comment: I confirmed it was my program by taking out the Directory.Enumerate Files    foreach and hardcoding the filename.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is that Directory.EnumerateFiles() is locking the _directory_, and when the directory is locked the directory entry for the target file can't be updated. Instead of using Directory.EnumerateFiles() you could get a list of all of the files via Directory.GetFiles(), and then traverse the array of file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the program is locking the file-handle when it enumerates the file in the directory.

Replacing this;

```
        // Backup each file in Array
        foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath))
        {
            Backup(filename);
        }
```

With this;

```
        Backup("AdventureWorks2012.bak");
```

Solves the problem.

Comment: Alternatively swap `EnumerateFiles` (Which holds a lock so it can read each file sequentially) for `GetFiles` (Which retrieves the full list at the start & doesn't lock the directory - the only downside of which is performance on large folders but that doesn't appear to be your scenario).